# Find the distribution of $Y=\frac{e^{Z}}{1+e^{Z}}$ where $Z\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $\sigma \longrightarrow +\infty$

Tags: probability, distributions

Find the distribution of $Y=\frac{e^{Z}}{1+e^{Z}}$ where $Z\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $\sigma \longrightarrow \infty$.

By a simple simulation it may be Bernoulli with $p=0.5$. Is this true? if it is, why?

The following picture shows the histogram of $Y$ for some $\sigma$.

[image]

```
  R code   [r_online_compiler][2]
  n<-5000
  mu<-0
  Y<-matrix(0,ncol=n,nrow=9)
  par(mfrow=c(3,3))
  for(i in 1:9){
        sigma<-10*i
        Z<-rnorm(n,mu,sigma)
        Y[i,]<-exp(Z)/(1+exp(Z))
        hist(Y[i,],main=paste("sigma= ",sigma),prob=T)
  }
```

[r_online_compiler](https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler)

Comment: no, binomial is integer

Comment: @gunes, The question is edited. I mean Bernoulli. it does not make sense, the distribution of Beta become Bernoulli for limited case $a=b \longrightarrow 0$ (one is integer and another is not). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Comment: The question is edited (binomial -----> Bernooulli)

Comment: Look at the CDF of $Y.$  Obviously $0\le Y \le 1$ and $Y$ is symmetric, so it suffices to examine its CDF $\Pr(Y\le \delta)$ for arbitrarily small positive numbers $\delta \le 1/2.$  A little algebra readily shows this is $$\Pr(Y\le \delta) = \Phi\left(\frac{\log(\delta)-\log(1-\delta)}{\sigma}\right)$$ where $\Phi$ is the standard Normal CDF. That gives you something to analyze: what happens to it as $\sigma\to\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

A closed-form expression of the PDF of Y can be obtained by taking derivative on $P_r(Y≤y)$ with respect to y. It turns out that Y is of logit-norma distribution.

Comment: It's a special case of the logit-normal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution. The pdf isn't hard to write down

Comment: To type the expression, you can use $\LaTeX$ here! On CRAN there is even a package `logitnorm`.

Comment: @Glen_b and kjetil b halvorsen: I am not familiar with LATEX to type expressions. I just updated my answer taking into account your comment. Thanks.

Comment: A great way to learn basic $\TeX$ markup quickly is to right-click on any mathematical expression you see on these pages and choose the `Show Math As .. | TeX Commands` option.  You can cut, paste, and edit the markup that will be presented to you. I do this often to obtain a faithful rendering, in my comments and answers, of the OP's original notation.

Comment: @ whuber: Thank you very much ! Will try.